# New to python. Was wondering if anyone can check if my code solves the problem question

Tags: python, average

Write a program that uses nested loops to collect data and calculate the average rainfall over a period of years. The program should first ask for the number of years. The outer loop will iterate once for each year. The inner loop will iterate twelve times, once for each month. Each iteration of the inner loop will ask the user for the inches of rainfall for that month. After all iterations, the program should display the number of months, the total inches of rainfall, and the average rainfall per month for the entire period.

```
input_years=int(input('Enter number of years:'))
for years in range(input_years+1):
    total = 0.0
    for month in range(13):
        input_month=int(input('Enter the amount of rainfall for that month:'))
        total=+input_month
    average=total/month
    print("This is the number of months:",input_month )
    print("This is the total number of rainfall",total,"inches")
    print("This is the average rainfall permonth",format(average,".2f"))
```

Comment: It doesn't, no. But you should try it out yourself and find out, then debug any issues. If you find a specific problem you can't solve, create a [mcve].

Comment: Questions about *reviewing* code should be asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help). StackOverflow is for questions with a *specific problem/issue*. Please read their help carefully before posting questions on the sister site, they have rules too.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you would try it out yourself, but I would like to point out that in line 2

```
for years in range(input_years+1):
```

you don't need to add that "+1" since it iterates over the range including 0, try this out by trying this:

```
for x in range(5):
    print("Hello World!")
```

it will print "Hello World" 5 times.

and also line 4 has the same issue

```
for month in range(13):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has actually two issues one is you are iterating one extra time in `for month in range(13):` because range starts from `0`. Another issue is inside your for loop you are doing `total=+input_month` so you are simply setting `total` equal to entry for last month. It should be `total += input_month`

Comment: This claim is wrong: "Your month is increased by 1 in last iteration and becomes 13 instead of 12.". It is 12...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problems with your code:

1. For loops are each one iteration too many
2. You are asked to do the calculations for the whole period, not per year
3. You are mixing up your variables, for instance `input_month` is not the number of months
4. You are not increasing total `total=+input_month` should be `total+=input_month`

Suggestions:

1. Fix the loops
2. Have a total for the whole period, not per year
3. Only get the input and increase total in the loops
4. Do the calculations outside both loops
5. Use period = 12*input_years, average=total/period

Comment: hi want exactly should fix in the loop ?

Comment: @AlexanderPaul The number of iterations, as every answer had told you

Answer (score -1):

Your code loops too many times for one year. It should loop 12 times yet it loops 13.

The formatting isn't correct when using Python 2. The code outputs like this:

```
('This is the number of months:', 13)
('This is the total number of rainfall', 13, 'inches')
('This is the average rainfall permonth', '1.00')
```

To fix this, use the plus sign between variables instead of using commas. When you do this, you will also need to pass your variables as strings into the print command.

If you are using Python 3, the solution would be to remove the () used with print. **Credit to [@SimonF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9521723/simonf) for the changes.**

It may also be a nice feature to display the units when taking in the rainfall from the user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are using python2, thats why you get the strange printouts. But Alexander can be assumed to use python3 by by the use of input and print with () (otherwise he is using them wrong, not you). The solution would be to remove the () used with print